# New SQL user - I'm trying to extract the latest record in my query. Accountant new to SQL

Tags: sql

For every AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID I want to return the latest record AbsenceBalance.BalanceTime for each AbsenceBalance.EmployeeUID

I have tried select max but it only returns the most recent entry for the entire table and not by AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID or AbsenceBalance.EmployeeUID

This is my query

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
AbsenceBalance.[UID],
AbsenceBalance.BalanceTime,
AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID,
AbsenceBalance.Mins,
Employee.FullName,
Employee.FirstName,
Employee.LastName,
AbsenceBalance.EmployeeUID,
absencetypes.LongName

  from [RiteqDB].[dbo].[AbsenceBalance]


  
  
  LEFT JOIN [RiteqDB].[dbo].Employee on AbsenceBalance.EmployeeUID = Employee.UID

  LEFT JOIN [RiteqDB].[dbo].AbsenceTypes on absencebalance.AbsenceTypesUID = absencetypes.UID 

  where AbsenceBalance.[UID] = (select max (AbsenceBalance.[UID]) from [RiteqDB].[dbo].[AbsenceBalance] where AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID = AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID)

  --where Select Max(v) from (values (AbsenceBalance.BalanceTime)

  order by FullName, AbsenceTypesUID
```

Comment: Which rdbms are you working with?

Comment: By last do you mean most recent? "The last record that was added?"
Or last as in, on a list of all records, I want the first one that was ever inputted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cte as (
SELECT TOP (1000) AB.[UID]
                 ,AB.BalanceTime
                 ,AB.AbsenceTypesUID
                 ,AB.Mins
                 ,E.FullName
                 ,E.FirstName
                 ,E.LastName
                 ,AB.EmployeeUID
                 ,AT.LongName
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AB.[UID], AB.EmployeeUID order by AB.BalanceTime DESC) AS RUN
FROM [RiteqDB].[dbo].[AbsenceBalance] AB
LEFT JOIN [RiteqDB].[dbo].Employee E ON AB.EmployeeUID = E.UID
LEFT JOIN [RiteqDB].[dbo].AbsenceTypes AT ON AB.AbsenceTypesUID = AT.UID    
)
select * from cte
where RUN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Sai! That worked even though I have no idea how it worked.

Comment: For your understanding try to run just the script that in wrapped inside the CTE (line 2 to 13) and try to focus on the column Run and understand what it is doing. maybe select top 10 or 20.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might need a group by [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), then either use an inner select in a where (like you have) or use this with an inner join.

```
SELECT 
Max(AbsenceBalance.[UID]),
AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID,
AbsenceBalance.EmployeeUID,

from [RiteqDB].[dbo].[AbsenceBalance]

GROUP BY AbsenceTypesUID, EmployeeUID
```

Answer (score 0):

In your where condition your comparing with itself that might be the issue.

```
select max (AbsenceBalance.[UID]) from [RiteqDB].[dbo].[AbsenceBalance] 
where AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID = AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID
```

following is wrong

```
AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID = AbsenceBalance.AbsenceTypesUID
```